# Getting the meta description of an external website in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

I'm building an app from which I intend to get the description of a site after a URL has been entered, like a summary of what the site is about. How do I go about this?

I tried using the http Meteor package like so:

```
HTTP.call('GET', url, {}, function (error, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(response);
  }
 });
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is it because I'm developing locally? Or is the http package limited to only JSON data? I'm fairly new to JS and APIs in general, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your running into a CORS issue. Since you stated that your new to APIs I recommend reading more about it from resources like the following; [HTMLRocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) and [Spring IO](https://spring.io/understanding/CORS).

Comment: @camelCaseD Thanks :) It's really been a pain trying to figure this out.